# Force HTTPS for Subdirectory (Wordpress)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently fresh out of ideas how to force https rewrite on a subfolder where Wordpress is located.

The Problem is:
Wordpress is located in this directory
www.server.at/berlin-alexanderplatz (cant be moved)
the URL looks like this:
www.server.at/berlin/alexanderplatz 
This rule is in place ->

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/berlin\/alexanderplatz\/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^berlin\/alexanderplatz(.*)$ berlin-alexanderplatz/$1 [L]
```

Now I would like to add https for this directory. How can I do this?

The problem is when I use the usual method of rewrite https it leads to a wrong adress because it uses the original folder www.server.at/berlin-alexanderplatz//

Comment: For clarity, could you add the method you tried please?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(berlin\/alexanderplatz/.*)$ 
    https://www.server.at/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: And this one
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: Anyone some idea?